# Random image in Google slides

Tags: google-slides

How could I insert a random image into Google Slides? like if I use a link, that always leads to a random image, to where I don't even know what the image will be once I present. -Thanks
(This link can be used to go to a random picture: https://source.unsplash.com/random/300x200)

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question from `How could I insert a random image into Google Slides? like if I use a link, that always leads to a random image, to where I don't even know what the image will be once I present.`. Can I ask you about the detail of your question?

Comment: Thank you for the response. This is not much coding, it is just a small problem. I just would like to know how to "enter an image onto Google Slides, that changes every time you present the slide." (changes to a random image.)

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `that changes every time you present the slide.`. In your situation, when the Google Slides is opened, you want to change the image? Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Every time I open the link to the slides, I want the image to change to a completely random image, from anywhere on the internet.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In order to achieve your goal, it is required to retrieve the 1st slide and the image from the URL. In this case, the OnOpen of simple trigger cannot be used. And also, unfortunately, in the current stage, Google Slides cannot use the OnOpen of the installable trigger. By this, I think that in the current stage, your goal cannot be directly achieved. I apologize for this.

Comment: That's okay, it was just something I saw going to set up for me and my friends, therefore, it's not too important, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As @Tanaike commented you cannot access a resource that needs authorization using [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions).

> They cannot access services that require authorization.

`onOpen(e)` Simple Trigger pointing to `"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request"` scope in this case

As a workaround you could change the images every day, using a [Time Driven](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) [Installable Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable).

###### `Code.gs`

```js
function changeImage() {
  let slideP = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation()
  let slide1 = slideP.getSlides()[0]
  let img = slide1.getImages()[0]
  // Fetch a new image 
  let req = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://source.unsplash.com/random/300x200')
  let blobImage = req.getAs('image/jpeg')
  // Get the properties of the actual image
  let [left, top, width, height] = [
    img.getLeft(),
    img.getTop(),
    img.getWidth(),
    img.getHeight()
  ]
  // Remove the old one
  img.remove()
  // Add the new one with the same attributes
  slide1.insertImage(blobImage, left, top, width, height)
}
```

Then simply add the function to a Trigger.

[image: ![Time Driven]